# Construct matching for half of the vertices, in linear time

Tags: algorithms, graphs, matching

Suppose we have a graph $G=(V,E)$ connected and $K_{1,3}$-free.
Sumner proved that every claw-free connected graph with an even number of vertices has a perfect matching (so, it is maximum matching).

Describe an algorithm to construct one matching of cardinality $|V|/2$ in $G$ in time compelxity $O(|V|+|E|)$.

I thought it in this way: the BFS tree of $G$ is acyclic so a topological sort (postorder traversal) on it may solve the problem (via https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claw-free_graph). But, looking some examples, I realized that there may exist edges that don't belong to $E$.

Comment: I'm curious: is Sumner's proof not constructive? Or is it, but you are trying to solve the problem for yourself?

Comment: @G.Bach of course it is, but constructing that matching in this way and select two by two nodes in postorder traversal, it seems that some edges that are not present in $G$ appear. Or do I  something wrong..I don`t know:D

Comment: Is the material available online somewhere?

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claw-free_graph section Matchings

Comment: Try using the fact that a DFS tree of a claw-free graph is binary. If it works out, perhaps you could answer your own question.

Comment: @Yuval FIlmus ok, I make the postorder traversal of DFS tree and yes, it seems I obtain a matching of cardinal $|V|/2$, but is that correct ?:D

Comment: I don't know, it's your exercise. Work it out and once you're certain that it works, answer your own question.